# Propagate `set -x` in [ba]sh

Tags: bash, sh

I'm using `set -x` to implement a debug flag in a shell script `A.sh`: if I call `A.sh -d` the `-d` flag will result in `set -x` being called.
Each line executed in `A.sh` is going to be printed to stderr, with a `+` prefix. So far so good.

At this point I'm writing a script `B.sh` which has the same characteristics: `B.sh -d` will also print each line with a `+` prefix.

I would like to call `A.sh` from within `B.sh`, and to propagate the `-d` flag.
And here we got the problem: it will be impossible to distinguish between the commands emitted by `A.sh` and the ones emitted by `B.sh`, since both will start with `+`.

A possible solution would be to call `A.sh` from within `B.sh` as follows:

```
propagate_options='-d'
A.sh $propagate_options 2> >(sed 's/^\+/++/')
```

But this is somewhat ugly and possibly not very portable.
Any better idea?

### Edit

After *chepner*'s idea I've simply implemented the debug mode as follows:

```
PS4="+$(basename $0): "
propagate_options='-d'
set -x
```

This makes it really easier to understand what is the output of what…

Comment: Use `PS4` to specify a different prefix string for each script? It's not *entirely* portable: "This volume of POSIX.1-2008 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option."

Comment: @chepner …maybe! Let me try…

Comment: Yep… put it as an answer and win your 'accept'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -x` uses the current value of `PS4` as the marker for each line of output.

> PS4
>
> When an execution trace (set -x) is being performed in an
>   interactive shell, before each line in the execution trace, the value
>   of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written
>   to standard error. The default value is "+ ". This volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems
>   supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

Comment: Never knew that. Very helpful in some situations!

Comment: If you have time, this answer could be improved by mentioning portability issues

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the User Portability Utilities are. Documentation is scanty.

Answer (score 1):

The most 'natural' way is to source the file. The shell recognizes that, and since you're sourcing debug is propagated. The kick - each source will add a"+" automatically at the beginning. Here is `a.bash`:

```
set -x   

echo 1
echo 2
. b.bash
```

and `b.bash`:

```
echo a
echo b
```

Running `a.bash` results in:

```
+ echo 1
1
+ echo 2
2
+ . b.bash
++ echo a
a
++ echo b
b
```

Note the `b` commands have two `++`.

Comment: Sourcing is not always an appropriate replacement for executing a script. The semantics are different.

Comment: This is really a good point, so +1, but I don't want to have the side effects of the sourced script in my first script (e.g. global variables declared or changes in existing ones)... so this ain't the answer. But thanks for the viewpoint :)

Comment: @chepner agreed. I think it's easier than micromanaging the prefix though, so if possible I think I'd prefer this. `PS4` would still have to be handled by the callee.

Comment: If you don't want the side effects getting back into the outer shell, use `( . theotherscript )` with parentheses to force a subshell (separate process).

Comment: If it's sourced, it shouldn't have a `#!` line, nor should it have exec permission

Answer (score 0):

```
PS4="+$(basename $0): "
```

i use this that i found somewhere :

```
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>>"path/trace.dbg"
set -x
PS4='[$(basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-inherited}):${LINENO}:${FUNCNAME[0]:-main}] '
```

Comment: Please make sure you double-quote the argument to `basename`, otherwise it will be subject to word-splitting. (For example, say 
if $0 is '/home/you/My Programs/foo" then `basename $0` will simply output `My`.)

Comment: yes thanks. (although I don’t use spaces in filenames, you’re right)